# Easeljs 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D Issue

Tags: html, easeljs

I am developing game using easeljs frame work i am getting following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Any One please help me.

Thanks in advance 
manoj kumar

Comment: Can you show us your code? It is really difficult to know the problem just by looking at the error thrown.

Comment: You need to at least include the code (snippet) which is causing this error.

Comment: A little late on this one, but I think this is caused by passing a bad image reference to the API.